# ask for access permissions on the fly in SharePoint 2013 using php

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, oauth

I'm trying to get accesstoken from the authorization code as described in here - but using PHP app.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687470(v=office.15).aspx

I was able to do this with c# using TokenHelper class.But I don't know how to manualy build the proper request to get the access-token from ACS using the authorizationcode(without TokenHelper class as this is a PHP application).

Can someone please suggest the request format for ACS to get access token using authorization code[not the refresh token]?